# A query to Find average value for each ranges?

Tags: postgresql, average, postgresql-9.1

Here is my table

```
GID | Distance (KM) | Subdistance (KM) | Iri_avg
-------------------------------------------------
 1  |   13.952      |  0               | 0.34
 2  |   13.957      |  0.005           | 0.22
 3  |   13.962      |  0.010           | 0.33
 4  |   13.967      |  0.015           | 0.12
 5  |   13.972      |  0.020           | 0.35
 ...
```

I would like to find AVG of `Iri_avg` for each ranges, 
for example..

each 5 metre (by default)
each 10 metre
each 100 metre
each 500 metre

What is the PostgreSQL query to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you give a small example of what kind of output you would expect with this input? I think this should be fairly simple with a `group by` but I'm having doubts whether a `generate_series` or something is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  Your data has two distance columns, which one do you mean?

Here is an example of how to get averages based on the subdistance.

```
select floor(subdistance*1000)/5.0)*5.0 as lower_bound, avg(iri_avg) as avg_ari_avg
from t
group by floor(subdistance*1000)/5.0)*5.0
order by 1
```

The expression "floor(subdistance*1000)/5.0)*5.0" gets the closest 5 meter increment less than the value.  You can replace the "5" with "10" or "100" for other binning.

This is meant as an illustration.  It is unclear which column you want to bin, what you want to do about empty bins, and whether you are looking for all bin-widths in a single query versus the query to handle just one bin-width.